# How to locate the First name and Last name text fields?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to inspect the textboxes as well as button,Please help me.I want to use sendkeys function for textbox.

**HTML Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
    First name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <br> Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: try //input[@id='username'] for textbox and //input[@type='submit'] for button

Comment: please read this url: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: @Mankeomorakort ,but both the textboxex has same proprty that is id=username so how can i inspect the second textbox

Comment: you can find element by index: //input[@id='username'][1]

Answer (score 1):

To send *character sequence* to the **First name** and **Last name** field you can use the following solution:

- First name:

  - *CssSelector*:

    ```
    form[action='/action_page.php'] input:nth-of-type(1)
    ```
  - *XPath*:

    ```
    //form[@action='/action_page.php']//following::input[1]
    ```
- Last name:

  - *CssSelector*:

    ```
    form[action='/action_page.php'] input:nth-of-type(2)
    ```
  - *XPath*:

    ```
    //form[@action='/action_page.php']//following::input[2]
    ```

Comment: please stop editing question titles to add "as per" somewhere.  It makes every question sound like it is being asked by someone with a poor command of the English language.